# How to subtract a hex from a strlen return then add to a hex address?

Tags: c, hex, decimal, strlen

I want to check a string length then subtract 0x3 (hex); then add to an address that was stored as hex; then put the result in an address as hex.
address is stored in a unsigned long int.

```
struct node { unsigned long int address;  char operand_1[12];};
```

does it work like this:

```
(0x)seekNP->address = (0x)seek->address +(( (0x)strlen(seek->operand_1)) - 0x3);
```

or like that:

```
seekNP->address = seek->address +((strlen(seek->operand_1)) - 0xF);
```

i understand all numbers are stored in binary at the end, perhaps my question should also be what happens when i perform arithmetic between hex and decimal size_t return type or even decimal?

do they all auto-converted to binary and then operation performed on binary?

Edit: say `char Operand_1 = "1000";`  and i stored it in `unsigned long address` via `seek->address = strtol(seek->operand_1,NULL,16);` 
will adding the strlen return value increment the hexadecimal variable(address) value correctly?

EDIT 2:  ok since its confusing to name a variable address out of context lets say `unsigned long int address;` is -> `unsigned long int MIKE;`

Comment: You say yourself that you know all numbers are stored in binary. That means there's really no difference between hexadecimal, decimal, octal and binary number formats, except for presentation. The hexadecimal value `0x03` is equal to decimal `3` which is equal to octal `03` which is equal to binary `101`. So you really can't "convert" a value in a variable (like `seekNP->address`) to hexadecimal, that just makes no sense.

Comment: there's no conversion, it's just binary. Viewing numbers in hex is just one of many methods to view data. There's no special circuits for hex addition compared to binary addition

Comment: BTW,  adding the numeric length of the string to the value stored in the variable `unsigned long int address`, does not change the address in memory of that variable.

Comment: @ryyker not adding to the address, im adding to the variable named address.

Comment: @topcat Does the field `address` contain the address some other variable?  If so, that points to another potential issue in your code, as addresses shouldn't be stored in an `unsigned long`.

Comment: "address" stores hex number incremented by an X value each iteration. this is part of a SIC assembler code.

Comment: @topcat But is that hex number a memory address, and how are you using it?  There's a good chance you're doing something else wrong if that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the notation `(0x)seekNP->address` is not valid C.  You may be thinking of a `typecast`, where the type of one variable is cast to another.  In any case:

```
seekNP->address = seek->address +((strlen(seek->operand_1)) - 0xF);
```

Is the correct statement.  (assuming there really is a `seek->address`it is syntactically correct.   Otherwise, (assuming the struct shown) this one seems more likely what you meant:

```
struct  { 
    unsigned long int address;  
    char operand_1[12];
}seekNP;
....    

//  interger    =         integer         - integer    
seekNP->address = strlen(seekNP->operand_1) - 0xF; //seems more correct given 
                                                 //the variable you are showing.
```

For clarification, as is mentioned in the comments, all forms of an `int` are stored as binary in memory.  Visual representation (i.e. whether it's formatting presents it's value as `decimal`, `hexadecimal` or `octal` make no difference to the value store in memory. Therefore, C statements can mix and match various forms of integers in it's statements with no fear the resultant value in memory will be affected .

```
int sum = 103 + 1003 + 10003;
int sum = 0x67 + 0x3eb + 0x2713
```

both result in `11109` or `0x2B65`

Comment: I am not adding to the address of the variable, i am adding to the variable. the variable is just named address.

Comment: @topcat - Okay, the variable naming threw me.  I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple example of doing an addition, a subtraction would work the same way.

notice when you make the compiler do the work and use data types and pointers the arithmetic is taken care for you... +1 or -1 to your **pointer** is movement to the next item you don't have to worry about if your data is in one byte, or 2 bytes, or 8+ bytes.

it looks like you are doing all the work yourself keeping an address in a variable of `unsigned long` which you are taking for granted it's 64-bit addressing {or if you did just `unsigned int` that's 32-bit addressing and hopefully you recognize the problem with that if you have more than 2^32 bytes of addressable space}.  So my recommendation would be to use pointers especially if you are addressing data that is anything more than 1 byte.

`unsigned long *pAddress;` means pAddress holds a value that is an address because it is defined as a pointer with `*` and it points to data in memory that is of a type unsigned long integer.  How many bytes in memory is a value that is *unsigned long* well that depends on your system and is something that is taken care of at the system level and something you generally don't have to or should have to worry about.  but on today's computer's it's likely 64 bits or a long int.

i think once you understand how this works it'll become easy:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   char a[8];
   short int b[8];
   int c[8];
   long int d[8];
   float e[8];
   double f[8];

   char *pa;
   short int *pb;
   int *pc;
   long int *pd;
   float *pe;
   double *pf;

   pa = a;
   pb = b;
   pc = c;
   pd = d;
   pe = e;
   pf = f;

   printf(" address of a is   %p\n", pa );
   printf(" address of b is   %p\n", pb );
   printf(" address of c is   %p\n", pc );
   printf(" address of d is   %p\n", pd );
   printf(" address of e is   %p\n", pe );
   printf(" address of f is   %p\n", pf );
   printf("\n");
   printf(" address of a+1 is %p\n", pa+1 );
   printf(" address of b+1 is %p\n", pb+1 );
   printf(" address of c+1 is %p\n", pc+1 );
   printf(" address of d+1 is %p\n", pd+1 );
   printf(" address of e+1 is %p\n", pe+1 );
   printf(" address of f+1 is %p\n", pf+1 );
   printf("\n");
   printf(" sizeof( char )      is %ld\n", sizeof( char ) );
   printf(" sizeof( short int ) is %ld\n", sizeof( short int ) );
   printf(" sizeof( int)        is %ld\n", sizeof( int ) );
   printf(" sizeof( long int )  is %ld\n", sizeof( long int ) );
   printf(" sizeof( float )     is %ld\n", sizeof( float ) );
   printf(" sizeof( double )    is %ld\n", sizeof( double ) );

   printf("\n");
```

}

Comment: I think by your statement: _...just unsigned int that's 32-bit addressing..._, you are really referring to _[data type ranges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx)_, (as opposed to addressing). The type of a variable does not determine what address space it will be used in. i.e. `int`, `long`, `float` and `double` can all be used in either `32bit` or `64bit` addressing.  Compile-time  settings will determine which addressing target an executable will be built to support.